# Objeto no instanciado (no hecho previamente un new)

Tags: java

Tengo lo siguiente:

```
public class Person{

private String name;
private double age;

public Person() throws Exception{       
    setName("Dummy");
    age= 12;    
}

public Person(double age) {
    this.age= age;
}

public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

public void setName(String name) throws Exception{
        if(name.length()>15){
            throw new Exception("The name cannot be longer than 15 characters!!");
        }
        this.name = name;
}   

public void setValue(double value) {
        this.value= value;
}
```

Y como programa principal tengo:

```
public class PersonCheck{

    public static void main(String[] args){
        Person person= null;
        boolean exit = false;
        int operation = 0;

        do{ 
            try{                
                 operation = in.nextInt();

                 switch(operation){
                        System.out.println("Person's name is  "+artwork.getName());
                        break;
            }catch(NullPointerException e2){//Error que se lanza cuando se intenta acceder a un objeto que no ha sido instanciado (i.e. no se ha hecho previamente "new").
        System.err.println("[ERROR] You have to create an person first!!");
```

La duda que tengo es que constanemente me sale el error de que no he hecho el instanciado y no se como ni cuando hacerlo. Ayuda?

He puesto los trozos del codigo que creo que son los importantes. Si se necesita màs comentadmelo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

tu primera linea del main es:

```
Person person= null;
```

Cambiala por:

```
Person person= new Person();
```

Es necesario construir un objeto con "new" antes de accederlo.